# Telerik radgrid rebind() throws Object reference not set to instance of object error

Tags: c#, ajax, telerik, radgrid

I have two rad Grid views on a single page. When i delete items from left grid it should be added to right grid and vice versa. I am using rad ajax manager. Please take a look at the code below.

```
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="grdAvailableIOptions" OnNeedDataSource="grdAvailableIOptions_NeedDataSource"
        AllowPaging="false" Width="500px" OnRowDrop="grdAvailableIOptions_RowDrop" AllowMultiRowSelection="true" RetainExpandStateOnRebind="true"
        PageSize="30" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnItemCreated="grdAvailableIOptions_ItemCreated" OnItemCommand="grdAvailableIOptions_ItemCommand">
        <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ID" Width="100%" TableLayout="Fixed" ShowHeader="false" GroupsDefaultExpanded="false">
            <GroupByExpressions>
                <telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
                    <SelectFields>
                        <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldAlias="-" FieldName="GroupName"></telerik:GridGroupByField>
                    </SelectFields>
                    <GroupByFields>
                        <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldName="SortOrder"></telerik:GridGroupByField>
                    </GroupByFields>
                </telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
            </GroupByExpressions>

            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridDragDropColumn HeaderStyle-Width="18px" Visible="false">
                </telerik:GridDragDropColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" DataType="System.String" HeaderText="Name"
                    SortExpression="Name" UniqueName="Name">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Price" DataType="System.String" HeaderText="Price" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                    SortExpression="Price" UniqueName="Price" DataFormatString="{0:c}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Delete" AllowFiltering="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkAddItem" ToolTip="Add Machine Item" ImageUrl="~/Content/Images/Add New.png" CommandName="AddItem" CommandArgument=' <%# Eval("ID") %>' runat="server"></asp:ImageButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
        <ClientSettings AllowRowsDragDrop="True">
            <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" EnableDragToSelectRows="false"></Selecting>
            <ClientEvents OnRowDropping="onRowDropping"></ClientEvents>
        </ClientSettings>

    </telerik:RadGrid>

<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" AllowPaging="false" ID="grdSelectedOptions" OnNeedDataSource="grdSelectedOptions_NeedDataSource"
        Width="550px" AllowMultiRowSelection="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        OnItemDataBound="grdSelectedOptions_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="grdSelectedOptions_ItemCommand" OnItemCreated="grdSelectedOptions_ItemCreated">
        <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ID" Width="100%" ShowHeader="false">
            <GroupByExpressions>
                <telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
                    <SelectFields>
                        <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldAlias="-" FieldName="GroupName"></telerik:GridGroupByField>
                    </SelectFields>
                    <GroupByFields>
                        <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldName="SortOrder"></telerik:GridGroupByField>
                    </GroupByFields>
                </telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
            </GroupByExpressions>
            <SortExpressions>
                <telerik:GridSortExpression FieldName="SortOrder" SortOrder="Ascending" />
            </SortExpressions>
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridDragDropColumn HeaderStyle-Width="18px" Visible="false">
                </telerik:GridDragDropColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Item" UniqueName="MachineItem">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblItem" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                        <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="RadComboBox1" Width="100%" Visible="false" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Quantity" UniqueName="Quantity" Display="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtQuantity" AutoPostBack="true" Width="30px" Text='<%#Eval("Quantity") %>' OnTextChanged="txtQuantity_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                    SortExpression="Price" UniqueName="Price" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPrice" Text='<%#Eval("Price","{0:c}") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnPrice" Value='<%#Eval("Price") %>'></asp:HiddenField>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Delete" AllowFiltering="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkDelete" Visible="false" ToolTip="Delete Machine Item" ImageUrl="~/Common/Images/del.gif" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument=' <%# Eval("ID") %>' runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete Machine Item ?')) {
                                         return false;
                                     }"></asp:ImageButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
            <NoRecordsTemplate>
                <div style="height: 30px; cursor: pointer;">
                    No items to view
                </div>
            </NoRecordsTemplate>

        </MasterTableView>
        <ClientSettings AllowRowsDragDrop="True">
            <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" EnableDragToSelectRows="false"></Selecting>
            <ClientEvents OnRowDropping="onRowDropping"></ClientEvents>
        </ClientSettings>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

here is the rad ajax manager

```
<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="grdAvailableIOptions">
        <UpdatedControls>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="grdAvailableIOptions"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="grdSelectedOptions"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="msg"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="lblEstimateTotal"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="lblConfirmationText"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="modalPopup"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
        </UpdatedControls>
    </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="grdSelectedOptions">
        <UpdatedControls>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="grdSelectedOptions"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="grdAvailableIOptions"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="msg"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="lblEstimateTotal"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="lblConfirmationText"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="modalPopup"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
        </UpdatedControls>
    </telerik:AjaxSetting>
```

Here is the code behind where i am getting this error

```
 protected void grdAvailableIOptions_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "AddItem")
        {
            try
            {
                int ID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

                MachineItems tmpMachineItems = GetMachineItem(AvailableIOptionsList, ID);

                if (itemRules.Any(i => i.MachineItemID == ID))
                {
                    btnConfirm.CommandArgument = ID.ToString();
                    lblConfirmationText.InnerHtml = identifyRules(tmpMachineItems);

                    // When there is a rule of allowed subgroups then this text will be empty.
                    // Dont show popup just add the item and make the related items available for selection
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblConfirmationText.InnerHtml))
                    {
                        SelectedOptionsList.Add(tmpMachineItems);
                        AvailableIOptionsList.Remove(tmpMachineItems);
                        lblEstimateTotal.Text = (Decimal.Parse(lblEstimateTotal.Text, numberStyle) + tmpMachineItems.Price).ToString("c");
                        CheckForAllowedSubgroups();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "key", "showRulesModal();", true);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    SelectedOptionsList.Add(tmpMachineItems);
                    AvailableIOptionsList.Remove(tmpMachineItems);
                }

                grdSelectedOptions.Rebind();
                grdAvailableIOptions.Rebind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting an error at this point **                    grdAvailableIOptions.Rebind();**. It calls the need datasource method correctly but just after calling need data source method it raises the object reference not set to an instance error.

Can any one point out what am i doing wrong here ?

Also i would like to know is it possible to just use ajax manager to refresh / rebind grid without using radgrid.rebind() method ?

Answer (score 0):

After Examining a lot i found that there was one null item getting added to my datasource which was causing this issue. So please always check for null objects before adding them to your datasource.

Hope some one finds this information useful.